# Launch differents commands shell in multiple gnome-terminals?

Tags: shell, command, gnome-terminal

I'm in debian wheezy and I would like to make a script, select it in a root shell, and when I press "enter", this would loads 4 gnome-terminals with 4 differents commands :

!/bin/bash

gnome-terminal -x tail -f /var/log/messages | grep ABC &>/dev/null &

sleep 1

gnome-terminal -x tail -f /var/log/messages | grep DEF &>/dev/null &

sleep 1

gnome-terminal -x tail -f /var/log/messages | grep GHI &>/dev/null &

sleep 1

gnome-terminal -x tail -f /var/log/messages | grep JKL &>/dev/null &

I've got conflicts... and doesn't work at all. Already tried with quotes or double quotes in differents places but not working. Somebody would have a clue ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, this should work:

`gnome-terminal -x bash -c 'tail -f /var/log/messages | grep ABC' &>/dev/null &`